How can I clear IKPictureTaker Recent pictures?
I was digging into the Telegram Swift code. I saw that they're using the IKPictureTaker for taking pictures in-app. A screenshot is given below

But, as you can see there's a Recents tab for the IKPictureTaker. I was able to locate the method to open the recents tab straight away - popUpRecentsMenu.
Question
The issue simply is that "The Recents images are never cleared". I've even deleted my Library/Group Container/... files, and all the other temp/cache in every way I possibly can. I don't know where the issue is floating around.
But, even though, when I run the app and check Recents in the pop up dialogue, I can see that pictures are stored there. I even tried uninstalling the app with no help.
Intention
I'm looking forward to implementing a fork where I can delete the recents at my will. At least to make the current flawed user experience a little bit better for myself :)
Code
This is the code that is being used to pick image:
func pickImage(for window:Window, maxSize:NSSize = NSMakeSize(640, 640), fileFirst: Bool = false, completion:@escaping (NSImage?) -> Void) {
    let taker:IKPictureTaker = IKPictureTaker.pictureTaker()
    taker.setValue(NSNumber(value: true), forKey: IKPictureTakerShowEffectsKey)
    taker.setValue(NSValue(size: maxSize), forKey: IKPictureTakerOutputImageMaxSizeKey)
    if fileFirst {
    }
    observer.completion = completion
    
    if let window = NSApp.window(withWindowNumber: taker.windowNumber) {
        window.appearance = theme.appearance
    }

    taker.beginSheet(for: window, withDelegate: observer, didEnd: #selector(PickerObserver.validated(_:_:_:)), contextInfo: nil)
}

Thank you.

Wow, this is an incredibly old crufty API. The docs even mention iSight, which hasn't existed in years. Is this really something you have to use nowadays?

That sounds way too interesting and creepy at the same time. I've updated the question a bit actually. The code is actually of Telegram Swift's - I'm kind of looking for ways to fix this persisting recents. So there's no way around this?
